# Remote debugging node app in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, webstorm, remote-debugging, visual-studio-code

I've managed to connect remotely with debugger to app running in Docker container but I am experiencing very strange behaviour:
when I put a breakpoint in line number 5 in my index.js file it breaks in various (potentially all) index.js and isIndex.js files (from different libraries) in line 5 (or next if there is no code in line number 5). It happens both in WebStorm and Visual Studio Code! Any ideas?
Thanks,
Paulina

Answer (score 0):

What helped was running npm update and excluding libraries when debugging.